# Arduino Uno with crystal

Tags: arduino-uno, frequency

Are there Arduino UNO R3s which use a crystal instead of a ceramic resonator?

(Frankly, I don't understand this cheapness: if you really want to save on component cost you can run both AVRs on the same crystal. The 16U2 always has a crystal.)

Comment: It would probably be an easy modification if you do it right at the ATmega pins.  Agree it's regrettable they didn't find a way to share the crystal between the two ATmegas.

Comment: Related (not duplicate): *[Does the Arduino Uno have two crystals?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/30964)*

Answer (score 3):

Some of the [Freeduino](http://www.freeduino.org/about.html) boards use crystals although the newer ones now use a cheaper USB to serial chip (the CH340) instead of the Atmel chip used on the Arduino Uno.

The [diavolino](http://shop.evilmadscientist.com/productsmenu/tinykitlist/180) is another build-it-yourself board that has a crystal. I am sure there are many others. The [ruggeduino](http://www.ruggedcircuits.com/ruggeduino) is another that uses a crystal and also markets itself as being practically indestructible. Their ["How to Destroy an Arduino"](http://www.ruggedcircuits.com/10-ways-to-destroy-an-arduino/) is well worth a read for things to avoid doing to your Uno.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the Arduino Leonardo uses a crystal:

[image]

On the Sparkfun site it's the same price as the Uno R3, so I think I'll go for the Leonardo.